# Draw vector tiles on folium map

Tags: python, extents, vector-tiles, folium

How can I have some vector tiles drawn on a `folium` map in Python? Or any other alternative to `folium`.

Context: I did some filtering based on some positions of map features I fetched from Mapillary and I now want to see if these tiles ended up being what I was looking for ie: tiles on west coast with traffic signs captured after a specific date.

Input: I have a list of `mercantile.Tile` objects which I want to draw on a map. I can obtain the (min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat) if these would be needed - using the `mercantile.bounds` method.

I thought of maybe converting these tiles to the GeoJSON specification due to what I've seen in the `folium` documentation, but it seems like overkill to me; I have a hunch there should be an easier way for that. What I intend to achieve is seeing all the zoom_14 tiles in the list I have colored on the map; something like bboxfinder.com (no need for the details on the bottom of the page, but would be a great addition). [image: bboxfinder.com]

Also, please note that:

1. the vector tiles I colored in the photo I uploaded are not of zoom_level 14; this was just for visualisation purposes.
2. I do not need the automatically generated bbox that you see comprises all my colored tiles (would be a great addition, though)

Comment: Update: I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054608/is-it-possible-to-colour-a-rectangle-in-folium-python) and looking into it. I think it's almost the thing that I was looking for. Investigating and then will post an answer to my question if everything runs fine.